# List vs Set when adding a GORM domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Say I have the following (heavily simplified) GORM domain classes:

```
class PhoneCall extends Interaction {
    Survey survey
}

class Survey {
    String campaignCode
    Integer clientId
    Boolean isDynamic
    List interactions

    static constraints = {
        campaignCode unique: true, nullable: false
        clientId nullable: true
        isDynamic nullable: true
    }

    static hasMany = [interactions: Interaction]
}

class Interaction {
    String clazz
    Instant dateCreated

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
        autoTimestamp false
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        dateCreated = Instant.now()
    }
}
```

I have the following simple code to set up these classes for a test:

```
def survey = new Survey(campaignCode: "TEST", isDynamic: true).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
def phoneCall = new PhoneCall(survey: survey, clazz: PhoneCall.name).save(failOnError: true)
```

This fails with the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [uk.co.nttfundraising.onitfhi.domain.PhoneCall]; SQL [insert into phone_call (id) values (?)]; constraint [survey_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [uk.co.nttfundraising.onitfhi.domain.PhoneCall]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod.performSave(SavePersistentMethod.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:196)
```

However, if I remove the line `List interactions` from `Survey` (making `interactions` into a `Set`), everything works fine. There are also no problems if I use `SortedSet interactions`, though the generated database schema doesn't seem to have any notion of order so I'm unsure about that solution. Google mostly suggests not saving the `Survey` (e.g. [this blog post](https://kousenit.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/silly-gorm-tricks-part-i-lists/)) but I've tried this to no avail.

It's only the `List` that fails, and it causes the insert into `PhoneCall` to completely ignore my `Survey`! What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

A caveat to using a `List` is that the item you add to it cannot be `save()`d prior to adding to the `List`. But more importantly, the proper way to add items to a collection when using a one-to-many association is to use `survey.addToInteractions()`, See [addTo*()](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html). But first, you need a proper association...

```
class PhoneCall extends Interaction {
    static belongsTo = [survey: Survey]
}
```

By replacing the `Survey` property with `belongsTo`, you get a proper [bi-directional one-to-many association](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/). Then, you can use/test it like this:

```
def survey = new Survey(campaignCode: "TEST", isDynamic: true)

survey.addToInteractions(new PhoneCall(survey: survey, clazz: PhoneCall.name))
survey.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
```

Notice that the `PhoneCall` is never explicitly saved, and `PhoneCall.survey` is not explicitly assigned. All of this gets taken care of when `survey.save()` is called.

Once saved, `someSurvey.interactions[index].survey` will reference the `someSurvey`.